# Page Reference not redirecting

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference

I am overriding the case select Record Type page. The page shud redirect to a custom VF page if selected record type is 'Support' else to the standard Case page

VF Page :

```
<apex:page StandardController="Case" extensions="NtnxNewCaseRecordTypeEXT" standardStylesheets="true" showHeader="true" tabStyle="Case">
    <apex:form >   
        <apex:pageBlock tabStyle="Case" title="Select Record Type">
            <div>
            <apex:selectList id="recordTypeDropDown" value="{!selectedVal}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!recordTypeSelectList}"></apex:selectOptions>
            </apex:selectList>
            </div>
            <apex:outputPanel ></apex:outputPanel>
            <div align="center">          
                <apex:outputPanel >
                    <apex:commandButton id="Continue" Value="Continue" action="{!redirectCaseCreationPage}"/>
                    <apex:commandButton id="Cancel" Value="Cancel" action="{!customCancel}"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </div>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class NtnxNewCaseRecordTypeEXT{
    public List<SelectOption> recordTypeSelectList{get;set;}
    public string selectedVal{get;set;}
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller = null;
    public String supportRecordTypeId;
    public String prefix;

    public NtnxNewCaseRecordTypeEXT(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.controller = controller;
        Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMapByName = new Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo>();
        prefix = Case.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix(); 
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult caseDescribe = Schema.SObjectType.Case;
        rtMapByName = caseDescribe.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        system.debug('******rtMapByName******' + rtMapByName);
        recordTypeSelectList = new List<SelectOption>();

        for(String rt: rtMapByName.keySet()){
            recordTypeSelectList.add(new SelectOption(rtMapByName.get(rt).getRecordTypeId(),rt));
            if(rt == 'Support')
                supportRecordTypeId = rtMapByName.get(rt).getRecordTypeId();
        }
    }

    public pageReference redirectCaseCreationPage()
    {   
        system.debug('****SELECTED VAL ******:' + selectedVal);         
        String retURL = 'ent=Case&RecordType='+selectedVal;
        if(selectedVal == supportRecordTypeId){
            return new PageReference('/apex/Ntnx_New_Case?'+retURL);
        }
        else{          
            system.debug('******prefix*********:' + prefix );
            return new PageReference('/500/e?' + retURL );
        }
    }

    public pageReference customCancel()
    {
        return new PageReference('/'+prefix +'/o');
    }

}
```

It above code is working fine for Support but for all other record type it does not go `/500/e?`
instead i see the following URL
`/apex/Ntnx_New_Case_RecordType?save_new=1&sfdc.override=1`

Comment: Is your debug statement showing the correct selected value?

Answer (score 0):

I changed new PageReference('/500/e?' + retURL ); 
to new PageReference('/500/e?&nooverride=1' + retURL );
and it seems to be working now.